# How to add a error message to the child event listener if the data is not exist?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I am doing a project on getting the data from the database. Now, I would like to show the error message when the inserted data do not exist in the database.

Below is how I use the child event listener and query function to search and get the data.

```
private void isTrackingID() {
    String userTrackingID = enterTracking.getText().toString().trim();

    //Long userTrackingIDNumber = Long.parseLong(userTrackingID);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Tracking ID = " + userTrackingID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HostID");
    //DatabaseReference trackingRef = rootRef.child("tracking");
    //Query query = trackingRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo(userTrackingID);

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HostID");

    Query query = reference.orderByChild("Reference/ID").equalTo(userTrackingID);

    query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                Log.i("checking", "this is value message");

                enterTracking.setError(null);

                //String IDfromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child(userTrackingID).getValue(String.class);

                    latitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("HostLocation").child("latitude").getValue());
                    Log.i("testing for latitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                    longitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("HostLocation").child("longitude").getValue());
                    Log.i("testing for longitude", longitudefromDatabase);
                    String hostUID = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Reference").child("uid").getValue());
                    Log.i("hostID", hostUID);
                    String customerAddress = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("customerAddress").getValue());
                    String customerReplyStatus = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("customerReplyStatus").getValue());
                    String id = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("id").getValue());
                    //String latitude = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("latitude").getValue());
                    //String longitude = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("longitude").getValue());
                    String status = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("status").getValue());
                    String latitude = String.valueOf(Userlatitude);
                    String longitude = String.valueOf(Userlongitude);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("hostUID", hostUID);
                    intent.putExtra("hostlatitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                    intent.putExtra("hostlongitude", longitudefromDatabase);
                    intent.putExtra("customerAddress",customerAddress);
                    intent.putExtra("customerReplyStatus",customerReplyStatus);
                    intent.putExtra("id",id);
                    intent.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
                    intent.putExtra("longitude",longitude);
                    intent.putExtra("status",status);

                    startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

So guys, how should I do the coding to show the error message when the user inserted tracking ID does not exist in the database?

Comment: There is no way to detect that no child exists with a `ChildEventListener`. Your options are to either add an additional `ValueEventListener` (the data will be loaded only once, even when there are multiple listeners), or even just use a `ValueEventListener` for  both scenarios.

Comment: which mean I can put the child event listener under the value event listener? Or should I use both event listener? ValueEventListener to check the data and show the error message, ChildEventListener to obtain the data?

Comment: Correct. I added an example of both ways of handling it to the answer I linked.

Comment: Alright, problem solved. Thank you very much.